# wp_nav_menu log in/out link?

Tags: menus, login, logout

I have a wp_nav_menu showing pages, but I'd also like to include a log in/out link, based on the current state of the user, which will redirect them to the home page.

I've looked far and wide, but how can I implement this in a wp_nav_menu?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `wp_nav_menu_items` hook to add a filter which will allow you to add your login / logout link.

Use `wp_loginout()` to display a status aware login / logout link. [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout).

Comment: Is there any similar way to display 'register' link in top menu?

Comment: Got it! Posted as a complementary answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to display `Register/Site Admin` & `Log in/Log out` link in menu:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','show_register_login_link');
function show_register_login_link($nav) {
    // The "Register" link is not offered if the Administration > Settings > General > Membership: Anyone can register box is not checked.
    return $nav.wp_register("<li class='menu-item'>", "</li>", false)."<li class='menu-item'>".wp_loginout(get_site_url(), false)."</li>";
}
```